# "assertEquals(boolean, Boolean) is ambiguous for the type" when using import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

Tags: java, junit5

errors while trying to use this type of `assertEquals` with `import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;`

no errors when using `import static org.junit.Assert.*;`

```
//import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
//import org.junit.Before;
//import org.junit.Test;

class isogramTest {
    //isogram Isogram;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertEquals(true, isogram.isIsogram("Dermatoglyphics"));
        assertEquals(true, isogram.isIsogram("isogram"));
        assertEquals(false, isogram.isIsogram("moose"));
        assertEquals(false, isogram.isIsogram("isIsogram"));
        assertEquals(false, isogram.isIsogram("aba"));
        assertEquals(false, isogram.isIsogram("moOse"));
        assertEquals(true, isogram.isIsogram("thumbscrewjapingly"));
        assertEquals(true, isogram.isIsogram(""));

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the signature (return type) of method isIsogram()?

Comment: What version of JUnit Jupiter are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statements such as the following are currently not explicitly supported in JUnit Jupiter.

```
    assertEquals(true, isogram.isIsogram("Dermatoglyphics"));
```

Whenever you have such a construct, you should use `assertTrue(...)` since it exists exactly for such use cases.

For example, change the above to the following.

```
    assertTrue(isogram.isIsogram("Dermatoglyphics"));
```

The same holds for asserting that something is `false`: use `assertFalse(...)` for such use cases.

If you feel that JUnit Jupiter should provide explicit support for `boolean` and `Boolean` in `assertEquals(...)`, please [open a ticket](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/new/choose) to suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

Likely `isIsogram()` returns `Boolean` object, not `boolean` primitive.
So the ambiguity is between:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(boolean, boolean)
org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Object, Object)
```

both can be applied, because the compiler can autobox/unbox primitives/Boolean objects.

In Junit4,

```
org.junit.Assert
```

does not have any `assertEquals(boolean, boolean)` method, so there it is not ambiguous.

Things you can do to fix when migrating from junit4 to junit5/jupiter:

- use `assertTrue`/`assertFalse`
- change method isIsogram() to return primitive `boolean`.
- Use  `Boolean.TRUE`/ `Boolean.False` in comparison
- use explicit casting `(boolean) isIsogram(...)`